# Call auth API before other APIs from home page

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I have home page in my application that has 4 section and each section is a component. From my home page I am making a call to 4 APIs to load data for 4 components at home page. Please note, I guarded all routes of my application with CanActivate guard which has code to return true is user is a valid user of the app. so all APIs needs to see if user is authenticated or not. All APIs that reaches to server must have a valid JWT token and if it does not have Server returns 403, and user is supposed to authenticate him/her-self.I have global Error handler that displays error page for any error. Since My home page is using 4 APIs and I am calling them Async, they all returns with 403, because first time they do not have JWT token. Since All returns 403 they all hits Error handler and reach to erro page.
I want to first authentication done and once done then to call all 4 APIs. How can I achieve that. Kindly provide some code example, because I am new for angular5.

Comment: Welcome, please check [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: I would suggest that you can make use of Interceptors for authentication purpose. https://blog.angularindepth.com/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6